# Get operator operands

Tags: list, prolog, operators

I have list:

```
List = [a=3, b=2, c=0].
```

For example, first element `a=3`, how can I get value Left = `a`, Right = `3`.
Left side is atom and right side is number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unification:

```
?- List = [a=3, b=2, c=0], member(Left=Right, List).
List = [a=3, b=2, c=0],
Left = a,
Right = 3 ;
List = [a=3, b=2, c=0],
Left = b,
Right = 2 ;
List = [a=3, b=2, c=0],
Left = c,
Right = 0.
```

Here, something like `a=3` is actually a *term* with a *functor* `=` and arity 2, with first argument `a` and second argument `3`. If you ever get into a situation where you are not sure how exactly Prolog interprets something you wrote, you can try `write_canonical/1`:

```
?- write_canonical(a=3).
=(a,3)
true.
```

In other words, yes, `=` is declared as an operator, but it is also an atom, so it can be the name of a term.

Comment: Hope you enjoy the `.` at the end of the answers as much as I do.